# Is there a way to find the max value in a table of a self-join?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, self-join

```
SELECT *
FROM Trips T1
WHERE T1.Cost NOT IN (SELECT T2.Cost FROM Trips T1, Trips T2 WHERE T1.Cost > T2.Cost)
```

This is currently my query that will return the most expensive trip listed in the itinerary. Of course, you can simply use MAX, but I have been instructed not to.

This is the query I have figured out that returns what I want. In the Trips table, it features the TripId, StateofTrip (ie MA, NC, PA), TravelMethod (Car, Train, Bus), and the Cost. So output may look like

```
987  CA   Plane   2000
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to do this in a Self Join, not a nested subquery. So something that starts like this...

```
SELECT * 
FROM Trips T1, Trips T2
....
```

Is this possible to do without using MAX explicitly? How can I compare values in a self-join and return the singular max?

Additionally, in the first query, can someone explain the nested example? I don't really understand how NOT in returns the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

You can find the max using a `LEFT JOIN` and `WHERE`:

```
SELECT T1.* 
FROM Trips T1 LEFT JOIN
     Trips T2
     ON T2.Cost > T1.Cost
WHERE t2.Cost IS NULL;
```

That said, I consider this a ridiculous approach to finding the max.  There are much better ways, including:

```
SELECT T.*
FROM Trips T
ORDER BY T.COST DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: the `limit 1` doesn't find all records with the maximum cost (which they may or may not want)

Comment: That is concerning to hear because this is how I'm being taught syntax. Thank you for making note.

Answer (score 1):

> query that will return the most expensive trip

"most expensive trip" is a trip which's price/cost is maximal - i.e. it is possible that more than one trip may be most expensive at the same time. So

```
SELECT *
FROM Trips T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT NULL
                   FROM Trips T2
                   WHERE T2.Cost > T1.Cost )
```